# Enumerative Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

Sam has $255$ cakes, each labeled with a unique non-empty subset of $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8\}$. Each day, he chooses one cake uniformly at random out of the cakes not yet eaten. Then, he eats that cake, and all remaining cakes that are labeled with a subset of that cake (for example, if he chooses the cake labeled with $\{1, 2\}$, he eats that cake as well as the cakes with $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$). The expected number of days that Sam eats a cake before all cakes are gone can be expressed in the form ${p\over q}$, where $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime natural numbers. Find $p+q$.

Comment: What's the source of this question?  Is it Project Euler or anything like that?

Comment: Looks like Brilliant Math. @mjqxxxx

Comment: Calvin, what's the story here? This is a cute but not hard question, and I know you are usually strongly opposed to posting contest problems here, so why did you put a bounty on this?

Comment: @david I'm not opposed to posting of past contest problems, but am opposed against those who want to want an answer to live problems without having to do work, thereby claims credit. I do answer past problems at times, if you look at my answers. This is a NIMO problem, but I didn't like another solution of it that I saw.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks for the answer. I was also misreading the question: I missed that he always chooses a cake which is available to eat. Without that proviso, the question is just how many times you can choose a random subset of $\{ 1,2,\ldots,8 \}$ before you choose the whole set.

Comment: @CalvinLin This is an OMO problem, not a NIMO problem.

Answer (score 3):

Fix $n>1$. Let $S=\{1,\ldots,n\}$.  In the end, we will set $n=8$ to solve the problem.

Let $\{X_i\}_{i\ge 1}$ be the sequence of random sets as described in the problem. $\{X_i\}$ is a random sequence with random finite length. Let $N$ be the number of days on which cake is eaten, i.e., the length of this sequence.

We will construct a different random sequence of sets $\{X'_i\}_{i\ge 1}$ that is equivalent to $\{X_i\}_{i\ge 1}$, but that is much easier to analyze.

Let $\{X'_i\}_{i\ge 1}$ be an i.i.d. sequence of random sets in which $X'_i$ is chosen uniformly from $2^S$, the power set of $S$ (null set included).  Define $I_i$ as follows:
\begin{eqnarray}
I_1 &=& \begin{cases} 1\text{ if } X'_1 \ne \emptyset\\
0 \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}\\
I_i &=& \begin{cases}1\text{ if } X'_i \not \subset X'_{j} \mbox{ for all } j<i \\
0 \text{  otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray}

Let $M_i$ be the $i^{\text{th}}$ smallest index $j$ such that $I_j=1$. For example, if $I_1=I_2=I_4=I_6=0$ and $I_3=I_5=1$, then $M_1=3$ and $M_2=5$. Then the random sequence $\{X'_{M_i}\}$ has exactly the same probability distribution as $\{X_i\}$.

Intuitively, $\{X'_i\}$ generates $\{X_i\}$ by repeatedly sampling $2^S$ until the next element of $X_i$ is found. At each step, if the generated $X'_i$ is a subset of some previous $X'_j$, $j<i$, then $X'_i$ is essentially ignored. This is reflected in setting $I_i=0$. Each time a new set $X'_i$ is generated with $I_i=1$, the next element of the sequence $X_j$ is generated.

Let
$$
N' = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} I_i.
$$
Observe that, by the argument above, $N'$ has precisely the same distribution as $N$.

We will calculate $\mathbb{E}(N')$. By definition, we see
$$
\mathbb{E}(I_i) = \mathbb{P}(I_i=1).
$$
Thus,
$$
\mathbb{E}(I_1) = 1 - 2^{-n}.
$$
For $i>1$, we may condition on the size $s$ of $X'_i$ and use the facts that $X'_i$ are i.i.d. and that a subset of $S$ with $s$ elements has $2^{n-s}$ supersets in $S$, and so
$$
\mathbb{P}(X'_i\not \subset X'_j|X'_i\mbox{ has $s$ elements}) = 1 - 2^{-s} \ \mbox{ if $i\ne j$}.
$$
We have
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}(X'_i\not\subset X'_j \mbox{ for all }j<i) &=& \sum_{s=0}^n 2^{-n} \left(\begin{array}{c}n\\s\end{array}\right) (1-2^{-s})^{i-1}.
\end{eqnarray}
Thus,
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{E}(N) &=& \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}(I_i) \\
&=& 1 - 2^{-n} + \sum_{i=2}^{\infty} \sum_{s=0}^n 2^{-n} \left(\begin{array}{c}n\\s\end{array}\right) (1-2^{-s})^{i-1} \\
&=& 1 - 2^{-n} + \sum_{s=0}^n \sum_{i=2}^{\infty} 2^{-n} \left(\begin{array}{c}n\\s\end{array}\right) (1-2^{-s})^{i-1} \\
&=& 1 - 2^{-n} + \sum_{s=0}^n 2^{-n} \left(\begin{array}{c}n\\s\end{array}\right) (2^s - 1) \\
&=& \frac{3^n - 1}{2^n}.
\end{eqnarray}

For $n=8$, this reduces to
$$
\mathbb{E}(N) = \frac{205}{8} = 25.625.
$$